# Can't locate that salvage mission objective

Tags: elite-dangerous

I just started the game. I've tried a few salvage missions, but I've found them very frustrating. In all cases, I get to the Nav beacon, then I'm told a new destination -- most of which are planets or moons. When I approach the moon, I'm told that the mission object has been found. I'll see a little blue icon popup but I always A) Overfly it and lose it or B) Lose it when I drop out of cruise drive.

So far I've yet to figure out how to actually approach and pick it up. Very frustrating!

Is there an easier way to locate them (like better scanners?)? How do I approach and pick them up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target the blue icon (point at it and use the "target ahead" button, or select it in navigation panel on left) and keep your throttle at 75%. If you don't have it selected as a target, it will be impossible to drop from supercruise at the right location.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this video, I found it a massive help.
Vindicator Jones on You Tube has a heap of helpful videos and tutorials.

It is possible to pick up cargo, pods, etc from the surface of a planet/moon without using an SRV too.

Hope this helps. Happy hunting.